# Python regex match, but exclude if regex match

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex for re.search that can match a string as long as the word `prod` exists anywhere in the text (`.*prod.*`). however, it should fail the match if the  string should have the word `orange` anywhere in it.

- `web-prod-green`     # should match
- `web-prod-orange`    # should fail to match
- `web-orange-green`   # should fail to match
- `orange-prod-green`  # should fail to match

How can i do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use regex? Why not just `if "prod" in text and "orange" not in text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a negative lookahead to exclude the presence of `orange`:

```
^(?!.*\borange\b).*\bprod\b.*$
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks tim. Is there an or operator where I can say either orange, or green or blue.

Comment: For orange, green, or blue, use: `^(?!.*\b(?:orange|green|blue)\b).*\bprod\b.*$`